# Get counts of the levels in summary(model) in R

Tags: r, glm, lm

I ran a GLM on a binomial model that had a lot different factors. I want to find a way to grab the counts of all of the levels. There are way too many levels to manually find them via table(). So for example, suppose I had a explanatory variable called color with three possible levels ("red", "blue", and "yellow"). Is there anyway to find the counts of all three levels?

Comment: What is the issue `table(data$color)`?  I'm not sure I understand your dilemna

Comment: My actual dataset had way too many variables to do this. 3 variables have over 100 levels each. I am looking for a way to store the counts in a vector. table() doesn't work in my case

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(data$color))` converts the table to a data.frame, from which you can access `Freq` as a vector of frequencies.  Or just `as.vector(table(data$color))`

Comment: Why doesn't `table` work?  You can also try `tabulate()`, it's a bit faster if speed is the problem

Comment: I already have all of the data from summary(model). I need a vector of the counts of levels in the same order as summary(model). anything using table will give me the excess baselines which will screw up which count corresponds to which variable.

Comment: Boy, a reproducible example sure would be swell

Comment: `sum(grepl("color", names(f$coefficients))) + 1` for glm `f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: make sure to remove your response variable (ex: df$response = NULL)

```
count = vector()

for (i in 1:length(df)){

    if (is.factor(df[,i])){

        count = c(count, as.numeric(table(df[,i])[-1]))
    }
    else{
         count = c(count, length(df[,i]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `summary`

```
x<-rep(c("red","blue","yellow"),10)
x<-factor(x)
summary(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do this with one of the internals from my package `library(imputeMulti)`:

```
# generate a reproducible example
install.packages("imputeMulti")   
# dev version: devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputeMulti")
library(imputeMulti)

data(tract2221)
# get counts on first 5 factor variables
test <- multinomial_stats(tract2221[,1:5], output= "x_y")
```